# how to get selected rows of master table and child table in jtable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jtable

here I am trying to write like this..

but this code is not working for me as i expects..

i am getting the alert message like

[{rcid:1}]

but i want alert message like this.. [{rcid:1, rdsid:10}]

Note: rcid is selected parent recordid and rdsid is selected child reord id

any ideas would be greatly appreciated.. thanks in advance..

```
function CheckForm() {
    var $selectedRows = $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('selectedRows');
    // var $selectedChildRows = $('.jtable-child-table-container').jtable('selectedRows');
    var myjson = [];
    $selectedRows.each(function () {
        var record = $(this).data('record');
        myjson.push({
            rcid: record.rcid,
            rdsid: record.rdsid
        });
    });
    $('jsondata').val(JSON.stringify(myjson)); // this will encode in a json string
    alert(JSON.stringify(myjson));
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar on my end.  I was about to go crazy because I couldn't find the answer.  I will first say, I'm new to jQuery so there might be a better way but I couldn't find it.

```
var $selectedRows = $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('selectedRows');
```

returns a list of the selected rows from all the tables above it.  In my case, I was 3 child tables deep.  So my $selectedRows had a length of 3.  I suspect yours has a length of 2.

For your situation I suggest:

```
    var $rcid = 0;
    var $rdsid = 0;
    var $index = 0;
    $selectedRows.each(function () {
        var record = $(this).data('record');
        if(index == 0){
          rdsid = record.rcid;

        }
        if(index == 1){
          rdsid = record.rdsid;
        }


        index++;
    });

    myjson.push({
      rcid: $rcid,
      rdsid:$rdsid
     });
```